# Update JobDataMap doesn't work as expected in Quartz .Net with C#

Tags: c#, quartz.net

When I try to pause my job I want to update it's data map so *"Paused"* status could be saved there. My code looks like:

```
public void Pause(JobKey key)
{
    var job = Scheduler.GetJobDetail(key);
    if(job == null) return;

    job.JobDataMap.Put("Status", "Paused");
    Scheduler.PauseJob(job.Key);
}
```

Job is paused as expected but it's status isn't updated and I can't understand why. What could be the reason? Are there some other ways to update `JobDatamap` of the job returned by `Scheduler.GetJobDetail(key)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I've figured out: Quartz updates job data map only after it's execution. So to solve the issue I have to re add job to the scheduler:

```
var job = Scheduler.GetJobDetail(key);
if(job == null) return;

job.JobDataMap.Put("Status", "Paused");
Scheduler.AddJob(job, true);
Scheduler.PauseJob(job.Key);
```

`Scheduler.AddJob(job, true);` line instructs Quartz to replace the stored job with the updated one.

Comment: It's 2024 now, is there a better approach to this? Thanks